# How do i integrate Linkedin login with React native?

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

There are really none maintained wrappers for linkedin SDk. Is webview Oauth the only alternative i have?

Comment: This video explains reactjs login - https://youtu.be/9MhLHkf7Ifs.

Comment: Question was for react native not react js for web

Comment: Ye, in 2021 nothing for mobile sdk, only webview but still no lib fulfils all needs, for me this lib worked: https://github.com/Swordsman-Inaction/react-native-linkedin-oauth , but I took the code and implemented it in my app directly without installing, now working on my library, will edit this answer once I publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OAuth SSO (single sign on) login 
https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth

And add the linked-in provider according to their instructions on the readme.

See linkedin instructions for setting the client id and key: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#

Answer (score -2):

Use [React Native Linkedin login](https://github.com/jodybrewster/react-native-linkedin-login).

Comment: Readme states works with upto version .22 of react native . It's out of date